# Guice: binding non-immediate dependencies

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Here are my classes:

```
public interface MyService {
    // ...
}

public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
    private MyCommand myCommand;
}

public interface MyCommand {
    // ...
}

public class MyCommandImpl implements MyCommand {
    private MyDAO myDAO;
}

public interface MyDAO {
    // ...
}

public class MyDAOImpl implements MyDAO {
    // ...
}

public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(MyService.class).to(MyServiceImpl.class)
    }
}

public class MyDriver {
    @Inject
    private MyService myService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyModule module = new MyModule();
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(module);
        MyDriver myDriver = injector.getInstance(MyDriver.class);

        // Should have been injected with a MyServiceImpl,
        // Which should have been injected with a MyCommandImpl,
        // Which should have been injected with a MyDAOImpl.
        myDriver.getMyService().doSomething();
    }
}
```

So this takes care of injecting requests for `MyService`s with instances of `MyServiceImpl`. But I can't figure out how to tell Guice to configure `MyServiceImpl`s with `MyCommandImpl`, and how to bind `MyCommandImpl`s with `MyDAOImpl`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other bindings and injections you need should be set up just like the first one.  Use `@Inject` wherever the instance is needed, and `bind` the interface to an impl in your module.  I've added 4 lines below (annotated 2 injection sites and defined 2 more bindings):

```
public interface MyService {
    // ...
}

public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
    @Inject
    private MyCommand myCommand;
}

public interface MyCommand {
    // ...
}

public class MyCommandImpl implements MyCommand {
    @Inject
    private MyDAO myDAO;
}

public interface MyDAO {
    // ...
}

public class MyDAOImpl implements MyDAO {
    // ...
}

public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(MyService.class).to(MyServiceImpl.class);
        bind(MyCommand.class).to(MyCommandImpl.class);
        bind(MyDAO.class).to(MyDAOImpl.class);
    }
}

public class MyDriver {
    @Inject
    private MyService myService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyModule module = new MyModule();
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(module);
        MyDriver myDriver = injector.getInstance(MyDriver.class);

        // Should have been injected with a MyServiceImpl,
        // Which should have been injected with a MyCommandImpl,
        // Which should have been injected with a MyDAOImpl.
        myDriver.getMyService().doSomething();
    }
}
```